# Compile error with SCSS if-else statement

Tags: css, sass

I have made a condition in `scss` but when I compile, the result cannot appear in `css` file, I hope anyone can help me to solve my problem, I put code in the bellow :

```
$color-sp: color-sp;
$width: 100%;

@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  @if $color-sp == 1 {
    .#{$color-sp}-#{$i} {
       width: $width / 1;
    }
  } @else if $color-sp == 2 {
    .#{$color-sp}-#{$i} {
       width: $width / 2;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to put **if condition** on **$i** instead of **$color-sp**. Check below code it will produce two classes .
try it on https://www.sassmeister.com/

```
$color-sp: color-sp;
$width: 100%;

@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  @if $i == 1 {
    .#{$color-sp}-#{$i} {
       width: $width / 1;
    }
  } @else if $i == 2 {
    .#{$color-sp}-#{$i} {
       width: $width / 2;
     }
  }
}
```

***And more optimized code for creating classes is below:***

```
$color-sp: color-sp;
$width: 100%;

@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  .#{$color-sp}-#{$i} {
       width: $width / $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oke thanks for your suggest, it's so helping me to make more clean and good structure code